# Add Viewers and Editors listed on Sheets to folders and files in Shared Drive using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a list of folders and files that need to be shared with various users (as Viewers and Editors) in Shared Drive. When I copied over the folders and files, it did not copy over the users.

I have a sheet with the following information below. I pulled the viewers and editors prior to copying the folder and its contents to Shared Drive. My goal is to run code to pull the new Folder or File Id in Share Drive and the viewers and editors respectively.

Info prior to copying to Shared Drive to get the viewers and editors:
*Path, Name, Folder ID, User Access, Owner, Viewers, Editors, Folder/File Date*

Info after copying to Shared Drive:
*Path, Name, Folder ID, User Access, Viewers, Editors, Folder/File Date*

I have used this code in the past and works just fine for MyDrive folder sharing (shared to <3 people) but when I try to do the same for a Shared Drive folder/files, it does not seem to work. Is there an easy way to add these users and silently sharing the folders and files?

```
 function setPermissions(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheetname');
  var start = 2;
  var last = sheet.getLastRow();
  var sheetValues = ssFilesSheet.getRange(start,1,last,ssFilesSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetValues.length; i++) {
    var row = sheetValues[i];   
    var id = row[0];
    var reader = row[3];
    var writer = row[4];

    var roles = {
  writer: [writer],
  reader: [reader]      
};

for(var key in roles) {
  var role = roles[key];
  role.forEach(function (email) {
    var resource = {
      role: key,
      type: "user",
      value: email
    }
    if(key == "commenter") {
      resource.role = "reader";
      resource.additionalRoles = ["writer"]
    }        
    Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, 
                             id, 
                             {sendNotificationEmails: false, 
                              // supportsTeamDrives:true,
                              supportsAllDrives: true, 
                              // useDomainAdminAccess:false });
                             });

  }
}
```

Your time and help are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To set a user as `writer` or `reader` for a file on a shared drive, as of now you need to set the request paramter `supportsAllDrives` to `true`, so in Apps Script:

```
Drive.Permissions.insert(
        {
          'role': 'owner',
          'type': 'user',
          'value': 'user email'
        },
        folder/fileid,
        {
          'sendNotificationEmails': 'false',
          'supportsAllDrives' : `true`
        });
```

- Setting a user as the `owner` of a file on a shared drive via Drive API is currently not possible. There have been feature requests for this, so it is likely that this feature will be incorporated by Google in the future.

UPDATE

Based on your updated code, if you want to extract several email addresses located in the same cell, you need to retrieve them as a string a convert them into an array e.g. with `split()`.

Sample:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < sheetValues.length; i++) {

    var row = sheetValues[i];   
    var id = row[0];
    var reader = row[1];
    var writer = row[2];

    var roles = {
      writer: writer,
      reader: reader
    };

    for(var key in roles) {
      var role = roles[key];
      var roleArray = role.split(", ");
      roleArray.forEach(function (email) {
        if(email !="" && email !=" "){
          var resource = {
            role: key,
            type: "user",
            value: email
          }
          if(key == "commenter") {
            resource.role = "reader";
            resource.additionalRoles = ["writer"]
          }        
          Logger.log("value: " + email);
          //Customize parameters sendNotificationEmails:false,supportsTeamDrives:true,useDomainAdminAccess:false
          Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, 
                                   id, 
                                   {sendNotificationEmails: false, 
                                    // supportsTeamDrives:true,
                                    supportsAllDrives: true, 
                                    // useDomainAdminAccess:false });
                                   });
        }
      })
    };

  }
  ssFilesSheet.getRange(i+2,6).setValue('Added User Permissions');
```

Comment: I found a script and tweaked it a little bit but I am getting a new error: Execution failed: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Invalid permission value -- for code line -  Drive.Permissions.insert(resource .... any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you mean you found a new script or the one above? Where it says `'value': 'user email'`, you should replace `'user email'` through the actual email of the user whom you want to give the permission (in quotes).

Comment: I edited the script above (original post). I am still trying to find a way for the script to recognize the "value". I get an error here: Execution failed: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Invalid permission value -- for code line - Drive.Permissions.insert(resource...

Comment: Your code will run correctly if allr etrieved cells in columns D and E are not empty and contain valid user emails. You can implement an `if` statement checking either `email` is not empty before inserting the permissions. Also, make sure to define `numRows` in [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) correctly.

Comment: Here is what I see in the debugger when I was testing it: resource: object = ({role:"writer", type:"user", value:"[\"john@abc.com\",\" jane@123.com\",\"joe@zzz.com\"]"}), role = "writer", type = "user", value = "["john@abc.com"," jane@123.com","joe@zzz.com"]" I am not sure why it is still failing.

Comment: Here is my test file - Tab: Sheet15, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xznoTAH2yS-Xnf-b3cCc0j8vxa9jS10WP1HjQapzNw/edit#gid=1060495402

Comment: The problem arises from the fact of how you treat the emails. Do not format values, instead retrieve them as a string and convert them into an array with [`split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) specifying `",  "` as separator. You can chose another separator (e.g. `","`), but make sure that you are consequent in its usage.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I knew there was something wrong with the Array. I have changed the .split from var roleArray = role.split(", "); to var roleArray = role.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/); since the email addresses are already have commas and just have to add double quotes for each. I am able to add other validations and it is now working. This would save a lot of my time! Thanks again!